# How to handle GoogleMap unavailable

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

**Problem:** `GoogleMap` is sometimes `null` (for reason's unknown to me).
As far as I know this can happen when Google Play Services are not installed.

**Question:**

- Is there a way to know when the GoogleMap is or will be available (`!= null`). Is there a good way to handle this other than showing the user a "I'm sorry but the app could't load" message?
- Is there a way to know the reason why `GoogleMap` is `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way. It's provided as part of the Google Play Services library.

You can find more information in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure). There is also some sample code in the play services demos.

Comment: So this basically handles the case when the Google Play Services is either outdated, not installed or other. But my question is: can the Google Map be null/unavailable because of other reasons, i.e. no internet connection, low memory, etc.

Comment: No, the Google Map should never be null if you have Google Play services installed, and your map fragment is setup correctly.

Comment: That's not true. The google map can be null depdning on when you try to access it in the activity/fragment lifecycle. If it is not yet loaded you will get an NPE.